# CDN vs. juntar JS/CSS

Tags: desempenho, aplicação-web, cdn

Entre as recomendações de desempenho de um sistema web estão:

- Usar CDN (no caso de jQuery, Bootstrap, etc)
- Juntar JS e CSS para diminuir o número de requisições

Acontece que essas duas regras vão uma contra a outra. Se eu usar CDN do jQuery e do Bootstrap, por exemplo, eu estarei aumentando o número de requisições. Por outro lado, se eu juntar o jQuery e Bootstrap num único JS e CSS, estarei diminuindo o número de requisições, mas não estarei utilizando CDN.

Desta forma gostaria de saber em que situações cada uma das duas alternativas me fornece o melhor desempenho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Se eu usar CDN do jQuery e do Bootstrap, por exemplo, eu estarei aumentando o número de requisições

Não é bem assim.

Primeiro, a requisição somente será feita uma vez e depois o navegador colocará o script em cache.

Segundo, se o usuário já acessou outro site que usa o mesmo CDN e a mesma versão do jQuery, não haverá requisição alguma.

Em geral, vale a pena juntar apenas aquelas dezenas de plugins do jQuery que você usa, mais os scripts particulares da aplicação ou site.

Mas considere que não há uma resposta definitiva que vai ser melhor para todos os casos. Seria mais uma questão de probabilidade.

Comment: O *browser* não faz uma requisição pro servidor perguntando se aquele arquivo foi modificado? O tal "erro" 304: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html

Comment: Nem sempre. Se uma data de expiração foi definida ele não vai verificar. Veja o item 5.3 [desta página](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/caching/).

Comment: @Andrey Além disso, acabei de acessar o [CDN do jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) monitorando o cabeçalho e encontrei isso: `expires:Fri, 12 Jun 2015 09:58:11 GMT`. Em tese, o browser vai usar diretamente do cache por um ano.

Comment: Interessante. Ainda assim posso ativar esse recurso de data de expiração no meu servidor, certo? A desvantagem seria não aproveitar o *cache* de outros sites caso o usuário esteja acessando pela primeira vez.

Comment: @Andrey Sim, é perfeitamente possível. A questão toda é que você vai trazer mais uma complexidade para gerenciar enquanto poderia delegar isso. Por outro lado, usar CDN na maioria das vezes vai trazer um ganho muito pequeno. A não ser que você tenha realmente um congestionamento no servidor, talvez você nunca precise se preocupar com isso.

Answer (score 9):

A solução depende do seu cenário.

Guie-se pela quantidade de arquivos que sua aplicação utiliza. Se suas páginas utilizam muitos arquivos (ou seja, muitas requisições são realizadas), tende a ser mais vantajoso manter o *bundling* (juntar os arquivos). Caso contrário será mais vantajoso utilizar apenas um CDN mesmo.

Mas nada impede de combinar as soluções. É muito comum utilizar CDN para bibliotecas *externas* (como jQuery e Bootstrap) "desafogando" seu servidor e aproveitando ainda o cache do browser e utilizar o *bundling* para seus diversos arquivos próprios (arquivos internos por assim dizer).

Comment: Sobre o segundo parágrafo: Baseado em que você diz que se tenho muitos arquivos devo juntá-los e se tenho poucos é melhor usar CDN?

Comment: Em qualquer caso é bom utilizar CDN. Isso ajuda no desempenho e  no SEO.