# Dúvida sobre CDN(Content Delivery Network)

Tags: cdn

Talvez minhas dúvidas sejam simples, mas me deixaram pensativo e querendo saber a respeito.

Visto que a CDN ajuda na distribuição do conteúdos, etc... Vamos supor que eu precise de contratar o serviço, então...

1- Quando se contrata uma hospedagem para o site, a CDN já vem inclusa no serviço de hospedagem? Ou depende da hospedagem?

2- E caso não venha incluso o serviço de CDN pela hospedagem, eu teria então que realizar a contratação, pois se trata de um serviço a parte, correto? Isso iria influenciar em algo pois tenho a hospedagem em um canto e o serviço de CDN em outro... Precisaria fazer algumas configurações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes da sua resposta especificamente sugiro que você leia os tópicos relacionados sobre CDN:
[Criando um CDN - content delivery network](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119766/criando-um-cdn-content-delivery-network?rq=1)
 ; [CDN vs. juntar JS/CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21202/cdn-vs-juntar-js-css?rq=1)

entre outros, mas aqui há esclarecimentos muito interessantes sobre definição, natureza e usos recomendados de CDN.

> 1- Quando se contrata uma hospedagem para o site, a CDN já vem inclusa
>   no serviço de hospedagem? Ou depende da hospedagem?

A hospedagem pode oferecer, ter parceria ou recomendar determinados serviços de CDN, por exemplo, eu utilizo a [DreamHost e ela facilita o uso do Cloudflare para CDN e outros serviços](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215873088-Cloudflare-overview). Entretanto, são assuntos distintos, pois você contrata um serviço de hospedagem (compartilhado, vps, cloud, dedicado...) para gestão de conteúdo, domínio, e-mails, arquivos, bases de dados e o CDN é somente um entre os vários serviços, sendo que em hospedagens mais robustas ou dedicadas, você pode configurar até seu próprio CDN, por exemplo.

> 2- E caso não venha incluso o serviço de CDN pela hospedagem, eu teria
>   então que realizar a contratação, pois se trata de um serviço a parte,
>   correto? Isso iria influenciar em algo pois tenho a hospedagem em um
>   canto e o serviço de CDN em outro... Precisaria fazer algumas
>   configurações?

Estudando os links relacionados acima, você verá que utilizar CDN para aumentar a velocidade é exatamente o contrário de deixar "tudo na hospedagem"; pois por natureza ao carregar o site, o conteúdo será requisitado em vários locais diferentes afim de proporcionar mais velocidade. Em diversas situações você não precisa pagar por um serviço específico, pois há uma série de serviços grátis para diversos tipos de conteúdo, como: [Fontes](https://fonts.google.com/), [Bibliotecas de javascript](https://cdnjs.com/), [Ícones](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/), entre muitos outros.

Finalizando, recomendo que analise em cada situação específica a necessidade de utilizar CDN, antes mesmo de utiliza-lo, pensar se é necessário essa requisição; visto que atualmente é recomendado para alta performance de SEO, juntar tudo em um arquivo ou compilar tudo junto minificado pode deixar seu site muito mais rápido.

Comment: Consegui compreender. Muito obrigado!

Comment: fico feliz em ter ajudado, abs!